How do I get my CSS to function in Chrome?
I am new to Python and taking a Django course online from Dave Gray. In the course we create CSS for Nav feature.
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: black;
    color: whitesmoke;
    font-size: 3rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
}

nav {
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: #44B78B;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}

main {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
}

h1,
p {
    text-align: center;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #81dbb8;
}

a:hover {
    opacity: .85;
}

My Layout HTML is:
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>
        {% block title %}
            Django App
        {% endblock %}
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <script src="{% static 'js/main.js' %}" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <a href="/"></a> |
        <a href="/about"></a> |
        <a href="/posts"></a>
    </nav>
    <main>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %} 
     </main>
</body>
</html>

My Home Page HTML is:
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block title %}
    Home
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <p>Check out my <a href="/about">About</a> page.</p>
{% endblock %}

I normally use Chrome and it did not look like his example. After reviewing the CSS I opened the page in Edge and the page looks perfect, just like in his video. On Chrome it is ignoring some of the CSS. How can I make my pages Chrome Friendly?
Here are 2 screenshots the First one is how it should look and the second is how it looks in Chrome.
Edge Image
Chrome Image

Which parts of the CSS are getting ignored? By that, I mean is it the entire nav attribute or just parts of it?

Have you used your Chrome devtools to see exactly what CSS is and isn't being applied? Are you picking up an older version for example?

The images attached (Edge Image and Chrome Image) show what was difference in appearance and what Chrome was ignoring. Another commenter helped fix the issue. Thank you for trying to help!

In chrome you could try to clear your cache.
In the top right corner press the ellipses 
-> Settings
-> Search for cache
-> clear browsing data now
-> change the filter to all time and clear

Once you clear the cache, refresh the page and your css should work

Thank you very much! This worked. I tried to upvote your comment but I do not have the reputation to do so. Kind of counter intuitive that I cannot praise you with reputation for answering my question with a valid solution.

i upvoted your question, you might be able to now

so close, Thank you. I am at 13 of the 15 reputation needed to do so. When I hit it I will upvote your answer for sure.
